# returning non-observable flat value from nested concatMap

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

My use-case scenario is following:
I have some observable chain and at some point I need to grab additional information from web service and basing on resolved information I'd like to continue chain or stop it by throwing out.

To wait for information from service I use `concatMap` (each value emitted form stream is mapped to new observable returned by service and I need value, nit observable of value). To flat all inner observables, all is enclosed within `concatMap`

Following code works well:

```
/* Begin of chain */
        .concatMap<Type, Type>((pld: Type) => {
            return this.appService.getInfo()
            .concatMap<string, Type>((info) => {
                if (someFailingCondition(info)) {
                    Observable.throw(`Failed`);
                }
                /* Pass-through operation */
                return Observable.of(pld);
            });
        })
/* Rest of chain */
```

But I'd like to drop outer `concatMap` in favor of plain `map` to operate on plain values only from main chain perspective. I came with `concatAll` solution:

```
/* Begin of chain */
        .map<Type, Type>((pld: Type) => {
            return this.appService.getInfo()
            .concatMap<string, Type>((info) => {
                if (someFailingCondition(info)) {
                    Observable.throw(`Failed`);
                }
                /* Pass-through operation */
                return Observable.of(pld);
            })
            .concatAll()
        })
/* Rest of chain */
```

But im wondering is there any other way to flat inner series of observables into flat values pipe once again after `concatMap`-ing them in inner operator series?

Answer (score 1):

You code is already quite straight forward, sometime it is impossible to have all observable flattened in a chain, you can further simply it to following, don't really need concatAll

```
/* Begin of chain */
        .concatMap<Type, Type>((pld: Type) => {
            return this.appService.getInfo()
            .map<string, Type>((info) => {
                if (someFailingCondition(info)) {
                  throw(`Failed`);
                }
                /* Pass-through operation */
                return pld;
            })
        })
/* Rest of chain */
```